# auto click buttons in seconds or minutes html

Tags: javascript, html, button, time, voice

i need to set buttons invisible and auto click this buttons like 1,2,3,4 etc buttons to autoclicked one in 3 seconds for exaple 2 button in 2 minutes this is automatik voice answear scirpt and auto click on links how can i change it to set up button time this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
       <script>
       <body onload="setTimeout('document.forms.myFormName.submit();', 9000);">
</script>
      <TITLE>sound</TITLE>
  <script>
function autoClick(){
document.getElementById('linkToClick').click();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout('autoClick();',3000);">
<a id="linkToClick" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">GOOGLE</a>

       <script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
       <input onclick="responsiveVoice.speak('dsfhsdhshsdfhdhdffdhdffhds');" type="button" value="Play" />


      <P>test intelect
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Your `<body>` should not be inside of a `<script>` tag. Nor should you have two `<body>` tags on the same page.

Comment: I don't know where you pulled that code out from, but seems some 10+Y old